# how to “catch” the break signal and return the best solution found so far

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I am using Ilog Cplex with Visual C++ 2015 to solve my problem. How can I send a  break signal to solver and make it return the best solution found so far?

Answer (score 1):

I take it, you are using Concert C++. Handling Ctrl-C (or break) is not within the scope of CPLEX.

But there is the [IloCplex::Aborter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cpo.help/refcppcpoptimizer/html/classes/IloCplex_Aborter.html) class. You can install a handler for Ctrl-C (see for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function)). Then also install an aborter with the `IloCplex` class and from the handler abort this aborter.

Of course, if your abort signal comes from a different source, you can use the same strategy: register and aborter and invoke its `abort()` function to abort CPLEX.

After CPLEX has been aborted, the best solution found so far can be queried using `getValues()` and `getObjectiveValue()`. These functions always query the best feasible solution found so far, no matter whether it has been proven optimal or not.